# openjdk: how to add site to exception list

Tags: ubuntu, java, digital-ocean

I would like to run an applet on my server and currently it is being blocked by
Java security.

On my development machine I was able to open control panel and to add a site to the exception list but now on my production server I don't have connected display.

Is there any conf file I could use?

I don't mind moving to different JAVA vendor.

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

You can add your sites at this file;

```
${user.home}/.java/deployment/security/exception.sites
```

Every url should be in separate line.

To log/trace you should add into your deployment properties `${user.home}/.java/deployment/deployment.properties`

```
deployment.log=true
deployment.trace=true
deployment.trace.level=all
```

Log/trace will appear in `${user.home}/.java/deployment/log`

Comment: I'm using virtualenv, so I had to create those folders and file but still no good.

Comment: Is there a way to debug this? How can i tell java picked my settings? need to restart it?

Comment: create the file(exception.sites) if it does not exist.